# Unable to search on specific boolean fields on files' properties in Google Drive API v3

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Google Drive API to list certain files and am using the `q` parameter on `files().list()` method. I'm able to get the fields by specifying `fields=nextPageToken, files(id...,shared)` but when using `q="shared"` or `q="shared = true"`, I get the following error `Invalid Value`:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%2C+parents%2C+modifiedTime%2C+kind%2C+mimeType%2C+size%2C+trashed%2C+ownedByMe%2C+shared%29&q=shared+%3D+true&alt=json returned "Invalid Value">
```

Is the above even allowed ? Because the fields I'm trying to compare against aren't present in the `File Query Terms` table at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms

Are the query terms provided on the API reference exhaustive and I can only perform searches on those terms ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `shared` is not included in the fields for the search query. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref) I think that the reason of your error is due to this.

Although there is `sharedWithMe` in the fields, this retrieves the file list of `shared: true` and `ownedByMe: false`. I thought that this might not be the result you expect. So when you want to retrieve the files with `shared: true` and `ownedByMe: true`, it is required to retrieve them after the file list was retrieved.

So, for example, how about reporting it as the future request to the Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) By this, Google side might consider to add new fields in the search query. Unfortunately, when I searched the same report, unfortunately, I couldn't find it.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)